# Android: How to/Show wifi (select SSID to connect) as dialog or popup?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, popup, wifi

I develop an application and want to show wifi networks as a dialog (popup).

My code is: `startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));`

It just show wifi setting as: 
[image]

But I want it show as dialog like this : 
[image]
I wonder this is wifi dialog or we can show another activity as a dialog.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Post it if you have found it please.

Comment: Thanks for edited my question.  Still stuck.

Comment: I'm looking for the same stuff... take a look on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162492/action-pick-wifi-network-on-a-dialog-with-avaliable-networks) :(

Comment: Did you find any solution?