# ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK on a dialog with avaliable networks

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a `Dialog` which shows something like `ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` but instead of open `Android Settings / WiFi` open it on a `Dialog` and if it's possible user could connect to any network avaliable from that `Dialog`. What I've at the moment is open a `Dialog` with a `List` of available Wi-Fi networks in Android, but this `List` isn't the same as `Android Settings / WiFi` thats why I'm asking if it's possible to open this `ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` on a dialog and work with it. If it's not possible how could I connect to network clicking on a `Item` from my `Dialog` with WiFi avaliable?

### What I've tried so far is

I've got a `BroadcastReceiver()`

```
wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){  
       if(mWifiManager != null) {
          List<ScanResult> results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
          showWifiListDialog(results);
       }
  }
};
```

A `RegisterReceiver()`

```
registerReceiver(wifiReceiver,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

This is the method that does the `WifiScan`

```
private void startWifiScans() {
 mWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 mWifiManager.startScan();
}
```

And this is the simple `Dialog` which shows the `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`

```
private void showWifiListDialog(List<ScanResult> results) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);

    for (ScanResult r: results) {
        if(r == null || r.SSID == null) continue;
        if("".equalsIgnoreCase(r.SSID.trim())) continue;
        String name = r.SSID.replace("\"", "");
        arrayAdapter.add(name);
    }
    builderSingle.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected "+strName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builderSingle.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

### Example with images

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Augn.jpg) and [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/motorola-droid-maxx/165590d1425418311t-can-t-get-rid-annoying-wifi-dialog-screenshot_2015-02-19-13-10-31.png) are examples or what I'm looking for.

### EDIT (This is how I see my `Dialog` at the moment but I don't like it yet....)

[image]

I'd like to show the networks with the `icon` with signal strength like android does [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GdIc.jpg). I think I'll need a ListAdapter or so? And then add the Network name, Strength connection, icon, etc... Am I wrong?

Almost the same question right [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28828179/4385913)..

I want to open it throught a `Notification` and obviously it doesn't matter if I'm on that APP or other APP... I just want to open it as a dialog and let to the user see what the user was watching.

Now what I get is this :

[image]

I'm using a `Theme` but it doesn't do what I want.

```
<style name="dialogtest" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This is the style and I call it doing this :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.dialogtest);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: I will look into this and get back to you. I haven't done this before ... :)

Comment: Okay I've edited my answer and I explained it more.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've been busy with work ... :(   I understood your question.

Comment: So far I have not been able to figure out how this has been done ...

Comment: It's okay... I think I'm gonna put a bounty to see if aomeone can help me :)

Comment: For connectivity logic, suggest you have a look at this library: https://github.com/kevin-yuan/android-wifi-connecter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the ui perspective you need a Custom adapter:

```
private class WifiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ScanResult> {

    public WifiAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ScanResult> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wifi_item, parent, false);
        }
        ScanResult result = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_name)).setText(formatSSDI(result));
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_img)).setImageLevel(getNormalizedLevel(result));
        return convertView;
    }

    private int getNormalizedLevel(ScanResult r) {
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(r.level,
                5);
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "level " + level);
        return level;
    }

    private String formatSSDI(ScanResult r) {
        if (r == null || r.SSID == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(r.SSID.trim())) {
            return "no data";
        }
        return r.SSID.replace("\"", "");
    }
```

I slightly changed your `showWifiListDialog`:

```
private void showWifiListDialog(List<ScanResult> results) {
    Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<ScanResult>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ScanResult lhs, ScanResult rhs) {
            return rhs.level > lhs.level ? 1 : rhs.level < lhs.level ? -1 : 0;
        }
    });
    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    final WifiAdapter arrayAdapter = new WifiAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, results);

    builderSingle.setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.cancel),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which).SSID;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected " + strName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builderSingle.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

the Wifi Item is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/wifi_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_img"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/wifi_level" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the drawable wifi_level is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_0_bar_black_24dp"
        android:maxLevel="0" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_1_bar_black_24dp"
        android:maxLevel="1" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_2_bar_black_24dp"
        android:maxLevel="2" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_3_bar_black_24dp"
        android:maxLevel="3" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_4_bar_black_24dp"
        android:maxLevel="4" />
</level-list>
```

I took the five png from [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/device/drawable-xhdpi)

For the Connection, the answer is ***yes it should be possible***. Accordingly to the documentation at least. You can instantiate an object of [WifiConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html), and feed it with info of the network you want to connect to (`SSID` and `password`). It is not a straightforward thing to do. If you have to take in consideration the different kind of keys encryption, (`WPA`, `WEP`, `free wifi`). Onceyou filled up the object, you have to call

```
mWifiManager.disconect();
int resId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(config);
mWifiManager.enableNetwork(resId, true);
```

Edit:

If you want to show the wifi-signal-strength icon with and without padlock, you could use custom attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="wifi">
        <attr name="state_locked" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and update its state in a subclass of ImageView:

```
 public class WifiImageView extends ImageView {

private static final int[] STATE_LOCKED = {R.attr.state_locked};
private boolean mWifiLocked;

public WifiImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (mWifiLocked) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_LOCKED);
    }
    return drawableState;
}

public void setStateLocked(boolean locked) {
    mWifiLocked = locked;
    refreshDrawableState();
}
```

}

Now assuming that the android:src of your `WifeImageView` is a selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item custom:state_locked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/wifi_level" />
    <item custom:state_locked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/wifi_level_lock" />
</selector>
```

In your Adapter you can easily switch between the two `level-list`, adding the following two lines of code

```
 boolean protectedWifi = result.capabilities.contains ("WEP") || result.capabilities.contains("WPA");
 ((WifiImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wifi_img)).setStateLocked(protectedWifi);
```

`protectedWifi` is evaluated true if `result.capabilities` contains `WEP` or `WPA`, and `setStateLocked(protectedWifi);` will switch between the two `level-list`s accordingly to its value. Of course, in the `wifi_item.xml`, you have two change from `ImageView`, to the custom `WifiImageView`.

Comment: Why `getLayoutInflater()` is giving me an error saying that's undefined?

Comment: `getLayoutInflater()` is a method of `Activity`. Depending on the use case you can either pass the context and use `LayoutInflater.from(context)` or passing directly the `LayoutInflater` to the Adapter

Comment: Maybe.. I added `<activity android:name=".activities.TestActivity" android:theme="@style/dialogtest">` to the Manifest, where `dialogtest` is what you posted. I just change its parent to `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`, and the result is [here](https://imgur.com/MS41q7l). The only difference is that I am not using a Notification to start it

Comment: Sh*t... I figured it out... I have 2 Activities... 1 when I have the `openNotification()`, `RemoveNotification()`, etc... and inside of `openNotification()` I have the `Intent` to the `Dialog` Activity.... And I've changed the `Theme` on both Activities... But I think this is not the best approach

Comment: Btw, to know if it's secured or not to put the icon with padlock I've to put the method on WifiAdapter?

Comment: I put everything [here](https://gist.github.com/bblackbelt/9c325af21e7e370a4ad9). Let it me know if you have doubts

Comment: First of all thanks for your effort, and now I've some questions... 1.- What `wifi_level_lock.xml` does? Because I don't understand maybe you misstyped the drawable because there are `drawable/ic_signal_wifi_1_bar_lock_black_24dp` on three items and only `drawable/ic_signal_wifi_2_bar_lock_black_24dp` in the last one, I don't need 4 drawables? With this it shows also if there's no pswd and it puts the icon without the padlock?

Comment: You need all four as for the other level-list. It was only a hasty copy-past. I edited my answer to add a quick explanation.

Comment: I meant `wifi_level_lock` so I've to do the same of `wifi_level`? download the padlock 0,1,2,3,4 and put it on each item?

Comment: Exactly, the name follows the same pattern of the other png. You should be able to find them easily

Comment: Well you helped me so much, I think you deserve my bounty.... I learned so much with your explanation, thanks again :)

Comment: Can I ask you something? I want to put [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Z1S.png) into a custom Dialog like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g5h1y.jpg) ... I've to change all the code?

Comment: It shouldn't be too much effort. Unfortunately I can't help you because I will not have available a PC for the next two weeks. Only my phonr

Comment: It's okay, I'm trying to adapt all the code if I can not I'll let you know but I think I will ^^ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the library [WifiUtils](https://github.com/ThanosFisherman/WifiUtils) to be extremely useful. To connect to a selected wifi network, create `connectToWifi(ssid, pass)`

```
private fun connectToWifi(ssid: String, password: String) {
    WifiUtils.withContext(applicationContext)
      .connectWith(ssid, password)
      .onConnectionResult(::connectWifiResultListener)
      .start()
}
```

Then, replace `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected " + strName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in `showWifiListDialog` setAdapter onClick with `connectToWifi(strName, password)`

The password can be empty `""` if the wifi network doesn't require authentication

The result will return to `connectWifiResultListener`

```
 private fun connectWifiResultListener(isSuccess: Boolean) {
    if (isSuccess)
      // do something
    else}
      // show error
}
```

In addition, I adapted `scanWifi` from the `WifiUtils` library with @Skizo-ozᴉʞS wifi scanning solution and it worked like a charm. So, instead of the `startWifiScans` method and the `wifiReceiver` which calls `showWifiListDialog(results)` I used

```
WifiUtils.withContext(applicationContext).scanWifi(::getScanResults).start()
```

And call `showWifiListDialog` in `getScanResults`

```
private fun getScanResults(results: List<ScanResult>) {
    if (results.isEmpty()) { return }
    showWifiListDialog(results)
  }
```